# Reloading array from appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

in my app delegate:

I store my array,then in my `viewController` I load them in `viewDidLoad` for my `carousel`:

```
        [carousel reloadData];

    self.images = ((RootViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).images;
```

I use this process so that when I delete items, it will still be retained, but what I need is when it will EXIT then RETURN to the View it shouldnt be retained anymore. In my case it still is retained, how to reload my array in my case? Thanks

Comment: you wrote *it should be retained anymore*, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

In your `dealloc` of your `viewcontroller`, release items and set it to nil.

On another note, why don't you associate it with the view rather than in the app-delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)dealloc{
   self.images = nil;
}
```